# shell script echo text name in for looping multiple texts

Tags: shell-script, variable, dash

I am trying to do this

```
text1="word1 word2 word3"
text2="word4 word5"
text1="word6 word7 word8"

for var in $text1 $text2 $text3
do
  echo $var" in "(__?__)
done
```

expected output

```
word1 in text1
word2 in text1
...
word4 in text2
...
word8 in text3
```

1. script will be executed with dash -> so no bashisms allowed
2. I am aware that shell is not a tool for text processing
3. does the loop concatenate $text1 $text2 $text3 before iterating or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text1="word1 word2 word3"
text2="word4 word5"
text3="word6 word7 word8"
set -f #disable globbing in unquoted var expansions (optional) 
for i in text1 text2 text3; do
    eval "j=\$$i" #i holds name, $j holds the fields
    for k in $j; do #k holds a field
        echo "$k in $i"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
word1 in text1
word2 in text1
word3 in text1
word4 in text2
word5 in text2
word6 in text3
word7 in text3
word8 in text3
```